# Home network SSH between two machines with two routers between them

Tags: router, ssh, home-networking

Ok so in my home network I have two routers setup, one from my ISP and my own Linksys router. I am currently trying to setup a Pi connected to the ISP modem/router but since my workstation is connected to the linksys router I can't even ping it at the moment. This is what my network looks like:

```
Internet Service Provider => ISP Modem/Router => Linksys Router
                                    V                  V
                              Raspberry Pi        Workstation PC
```

My linksys router has a static IP reserved in the Modem/Router as I have forwarded some ports to host some game servers but I get a timeout whenever I try to ping the Raspberry Pi. The modem/router is address `192.168.2.1` when trying to access it from my PC, the linksys is `192.168.1.1` but is also `192.168.2.10` when I look at the IPS modem/router web interface. Is there something special I need to do to allow my workstation to SSH in to the Pi so I can not only set it up but also maintain it?

Comment: Do you know the PI's IP? the way your network is set up, you should not need port forwarding or any special configuration to connect from the workstation (inner network) to the PI (outer network). you would need those if you wanted to connect from the PI to the workstation, but not the other way around. I'd try to confirm that the pi has a IP in the 192.168.2.0/24 network, and has SSH enabled. you mention setting up the PI, but note that they do not ship with SSH enabled, and ssh is usually configured by default to forbid root login.

Comment: Do you have another way to connect to the Pi (another computer in the same network as Pi, or HDMI, or serial cable)? Run a packet capture and check whether it's receiving the "ping" packets from your workstation at all, and whether it's replying (and which IP&MAC it's replying to).

Comment: I made sure to setup SSH when flashing the SD card and checked it on the 2nd router's network. I ended up figuring it out though, I set the second router to use the 1st router as DNS server since the second was acting as it's own DNS, not sure why that worked but it did. Thankfully I had to do that anyways so that the pihole would also act on the network traffic from the 2nd router.